# Ruby on Rails: Calling Model method in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to achieve Paypal integration with rails. Following this (http://railscasts.com/episodes/141-paypal-basics) I have a function in model which call paypal service with a return url. I have added a link in view that links to method in model.But some how rails is not able to get function in model.

What am i doing wrong?

My View :

```
form_for @order do |f|
- if @order.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
        h2 = "#{pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this order from being saved:"
        ul
            - @order.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
                li = message
.field
    = f.label :first_name
    = f.text_field :first_name
.field
    = f.label :last_name
    = f.text_field :last_name
.field
    = f.label :card_number
    = f.text_field :card_number
.field
    = f.label :card_verification, "Card Verification Value (CVV)"
    = f.text_field :card_verification
.field
    = f.label :card_expires_on
    = f.date_select :card_expires_on, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: (Date.today.year+10), add_month_numbers: true, discard_day: true}, {class: "browser-default"}
.field
    = link_to 'PayPal', @order.paypal_url(current_user)<= link to model function 
.actions
    = f.submit
```

My Model : defined following function.

```
def paypal_url(return_url)
values = {
  :business => 'xxxxx.XXXXX@techflex.com',
  :cmd => '_cart',
  :upload => 1,
  :return => return_url,
  :invoice => id
}

values.merge!({
  "amount_#{1}" => item.unit_price,
  "item_name_#{1}" => item.product.name,
  "item_number_#{1}" => item.id,
  "quantity_#{1}" => item.quantity
})

"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
```

end

Error :

```
NoMethodError in Orders#new
Showing C:/Users/Suniljadhav/SourceCode/TrainStation/app/views/orders/_form.html.slim where line #24 raised:

private method `paypal_url' called for #<Order:0x5e49bf8>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/orders/new.html.slim
```

Rails.root: C:/Users/Suniljadhav/Source Code/TrainStation

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @mlovic :  Edited my question for error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `paypal_url` is a private method and you are trying to call it from outside of its class.

In your `Order` class you probably have the keyword `private`. Every method below that keyword will be declared private (as opposed to public) and an error will be thrown if you try to call it from outside the class. Private methods can only be called from within the class where they are defined. So try moving the definition of `paypal_url` so that it appears before `private` in your class.

You can read more about how this works [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_access_control.html), and about the reasons behind it [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_access_control.html).

Comment: : Great i was playing stupid should have figured it out by myself. Any ways thank you so much for the help